# numerical test of constant scalar curvature Kahler metrics (Csck) on non-compact manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

On compact Kahler manifolds, Calabi functional $C(\omega)$ and Futaki invariant $F([w],h)$ and also Mabuchi energy $M(\phi(t))$ are useful numerical test for the existence of Csck. 
However in the non-compact case, (especially in Asymptotically locally Euclidean (ALE) case, or in general non-compact manifolds with "good" boundary at infinity), is there still some "good" numerical test of Csck like those mentioned above?

Comment: for example for the cone of Sasakian manifolds which are non-compact you can define Mabuchi functional .